# Get the more repeated register in the database Django

Tags: django, view, annotate

I have to do statistics on the patient with medical visits, I'm trying to use annotate, but I doesn't work, the way I want it.
I need to get the member id(A7069001-03) with the more medical visits.

```
consultassub = consultasSubsecuentes.objects.annotate(num_id_credencial=Count('Consultasbc_credencial')).order_by('-num_id_credencial')[:5]
```

I get this:

```
A7069001-03 
A7069001-03 
A7039001-01 
A7045053-01 
A7045053-01
```

But I only need the one with more visits and the number of visits.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is `A7069001-03` exactly, and what are you trying to get, exactly?

Comment: Easier to help if you show the models your using.